# Fullcalendar dateIncrement on click(Prev/Next) move one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

The below example is working good. I want **move the date one by one on click prev/next** when default view.
The default view currently `timelineWeek` for two weeks. I want the customization for monthly, weekly, yearly also.

I have tried `dateIncrement: { days: 1 }`. But its not working on default view.

[image: ref]

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    contentHeight: 610,
    scrollTime: '00:00',
    displayEventTime: false,
    displayEventEnd: false,
    timeFormat: 'h:mma',
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    //slotDuration: '24:00',
    titleFormat: 'ddd DD MMM YYYY',
    columnFormat: 'ddd DD/M',
    resourceAreaWidth: 200,
    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
    duration: {
      days: 15
    },
    slotDuration: {
      "hours": 12
    },
    slotLabelInterval: {
      "hours": 24
    },
    minTime: "00:00:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    height: 610,
    contentHeight: "40",
    header: {
      left: 'prev, today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'oneweek,twoweek,onemonth,oneyear,next'
    },
    views: {
      oneyear: {
        buttonText: 'One Year',
        type: 'timelineYear',
        dateIncrement: { days: 1 }
      },
      twoweek: {
         buttonText: 'Two Week',
         type: 'timelineWeek',
         dragScroll: true,
         dateIncrement: { days: 1 },
         duration: { days: 15 }
     },
      onemonth: {
        buttonText: 'One Month',
        type: 'timelineMonth',
        dateIncrement: { days: 1 }
      },
    },
    //hiddenDays: [ 10 ],
    businessHours: {
      start: '09:00',
      end: '20:00'
    },
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources'
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@1.10.0/dist/scheduler.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: "its not working on default view"...because you haven't told it to work on the "default" view. In fact you haven't defined your "oneweek" view at all, which is why you don't have a button for it. And since you didn't specify any other default view, it falls back to using a standard `resourceTimelineWeek` view. Your dateIncrement option is not applied to that view. It's not complicated - if you want to use a setting with a particular view then you have to specify it. Actually there is no problem, nothing is "not working", you've just forgotten to add some settings.

Comment: @ADyson. Okay Noted.